# Any "adobe flash" alternarives?

Tags: flash

Dear All,
I'm searching for alternative technology to be used in web development similar to adobe flash and action script. It should work under Linux environment.

It's also better not to be a Microsoft technology.

Any ideas ??

Comment: What functionality and techniques are you looking for? And why is Flash not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depends of your knowledge about programming and what you want to do with (your audience).

For pure web development, on the same way as Flash can do, use web languages like HTML, CSS, JavaScript or SVG (see [examples](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/)). But it's limited by browsers implementations.

You can also use others web plugins like Java (Applets, JavaFX, Processing), Unity, NativeClient (NaCl Chrome)

But if just using Linux and you only need developer tools for programming Flash, you can use any text editor you want (like eclipse or vim) to edit ActionScript files and compile it with [FlexSDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/) or using [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX is the only thing that comes to mind, however, I wouldn't recommend it.